# Exactly what is Aizawa-sensei's quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia, chapter 6:

> Midoriya throws the ball, and Aizawa erases his Quirk, making him fail a first time.

During this time, he grabs the student with his scarf, while **not touching it**. The drawn version is ambiguous, but the anime version is clear about that statement.

How so ? His quirk is only quirk erasing, not something about gravity or scarf controlling. Is there even a valid reason about that ?

Links to evidence:

[image: Ambiguous hold over the left shoulder ?]

[Video extract (sorry for the commercial channel)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RMhjQZUQqg&t=57s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aizawa-sensei's quirk is [**Erasure**](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Shota_Aizawa#Quirk_and_Abilities):

> Shota's Quirk gives him the ability to nullify anyone's Quirk by looking at them.

The cloth like material is not a quirk nor is it quirk controlled. It is called the [**Capturing Weapon**](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Capturing_Weapon):

> The Capturing Weapon is a cloth-like equipment made from carbon fibers and a special metal alloy. Shota Aizawa wears it around his neck at all times.
>
> **He is able to manipulate the weapon to ensnare his targets and immobilize them**. He uses the weapon as a powerful combo with his Erasure Quirk and as a precaution for Mutant-type Quirk users who are immune to his nullification power.

Comment: So he is kind of, "able" to use by himself. I see, thank you.